# Apache/Tomcat Webserver using AJP Proxy - How to rewrite/redirect URL

Tags: apache-2.4, tomcat, redirect

I have a web server running Jaspersoft Server on Tomcat, using Apache with AJP Proxy for SSL.  Right now, when we navigate to the serverhostname, it redirects us to https://serverhostname.  Instead I want it redirect to https://serverhostname/jasperserver and go right into the application.  (This URL is linked with our CAS SSO system, so it would redirect again to a login screen, but I think that'd be fine.)

I tried using VirtualHost, but it doesn't seem to do anything. Then again, I could be using it wrong.

```
<VirtualHost *>
 ServerName serverhostname
 Redirect permanent / https://serverhostname/jasperserver/
</VirtualHost>
```

Proxy code

```
<Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass / ajp://serverhostname:8009/
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://serverhostname:8009/

<Location / >
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Location>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I've also tried adding `RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ https://serverhostname/jasperserver/` to no avail as well.  I'm guessing I need to actually perform the rewrite in Tomcat, just no sure how to do that...

Comment: Pls post apache proxy config

Comment: Posted the proxy code within my httpd.conf file, hope that's what you're looking for.

Comment: try change to `ProxyPass /jasperserver/ ajp://serverhostname:8009/jasperserver/`, `ProxyPassReverse /jasperserver/ ajp://serverhostname:8009/jasperserver/` and check `Redirect permanent / https://serverhostname/jasperserver/` it works

Comment: I tried that exactly as you wrote here, and it took me to the generic Apache homescreen, so I think it isn't connecting with Tomcat at all.  I then edited it to `ProxyPass / ajp://serverhostname:8009/jasperserver/, ProxyPassReverse / ajp://serverhostname:8009/jasperserver/` and now when I go to serverhostname it seems to redirect me.  It goes through CAS and I log in, but it takes me to a "Page Not Found" page with URL serverhostname/jasperserver/loginsuccess.html.  I've never seen this page before, and isn't correctly (obviously).  I'll keep checking logs and trying things though!